# Take input value from form with loop and create array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have problem with JavaScript function. How can I take the value from the form inputs with loop ?

I try something like

```
var values =[];

for (var h=1; h<=arrange;++h){
  values[h]=parseFloat($('#inputr2"+h+"').val()); 
}
```

How can I add `h` in the *id* , as `inputr20 (if h=0)` ,`inputr21 (h=1)` ,anyone can help ?

Comment: Escape your strings properly. " ends with " and ' ends with ', so `'#inputr2' + h` But JQuery probably has methods to work on forms, so look at the docs for alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
var values =[];

for (var h=1; h<=arrange;++h){
  values[h]=parseFloat($(String("#inputr2"+h)).val()); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Array's index are 0 based. You have to assign the value to the index `h-1`. You do not need to decrease that, if you start the loop from `0`. Also the string id you are generating is not properly formatted. You can try the following way:

```js
var values =[];
var arrange = 2
for (var h=0; h<arrange;h++){
  values[h]=parseFloat($("#inputr2"+h).val()); 
  //Or you can simply use push() which does not require index.
  //values.push(parseFloat($("#inputr2"+h).val()));
}
console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputr20" value="11.11"/>
<input id="inputr21" value="22.22"/>
```

If you want get all the input values having *id* [Starts With](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), you can use `map()` and `get()` like the following way:

```js
var values = $('[id^=inputr2]').map((i, el) => parseFloat($(el).val())).get();
console.log(values)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputr21" value="11.11"/>
<input id="inputr22" value="22.22"/>
```